# request alternatively take long time

Tags: nginx, cluster-analysis, load-balancing, nginx-config

I'm install a Wordpress Cluster but I'm use it with a personal php application

My problem is sometimes requests take very long time to get response from the cluster (cf image) It's not the same request every time and the server's metrics are OK !

My personal domain point on ip of the load balancer with A record

Example of requests and times

[image: Example of requests time]

I try to restart cluster, optimize requests using cache .... no solution

After search, I'm sure the problem isn't at DB level because for similar data and request on other simple server it's ok. I think the problem is between nginx load balancer or nginx cluster in Jelastic ... maybe due to security conf or other